# Unique column style within wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I'm fairly new to wpf, and I'm having a problem with my datagrid. I'd like a subset of the columns to have a unique style, similar to this [similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gexfU.jpg).

I haven't found any methods that would let me achieve this, either in xaml or the code behind. I'm working with VB for this, but I don't mind ideas that use c# as I can use that as a starting point.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose the type and style of the columns of the datagrid in the following way (Text of column 1 and 2 lighter and column 3 normal ):

```
 <DataGrid 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        AlternatingRowBackground="#"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridCollection}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!--Column 1-->
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Property1}" Header="Header1" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <!--Column 2-->
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Property2}" Header="Header2" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <!--Column 3-->
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Property3}" Header="Header3" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

If you want to modify the background of the DataGridCell and keep the AlternatingRowBackground you can modify directly the CellStyle (Column 1 and 2 lighter and column 3 normal )

```
   <DataGrid 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        AlternatingRowBackground="#"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridCollection}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!--Column 1-->
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Property1}" Header="Header1" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#50FFFFFF"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <!--Column 2-->
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Property2}" Header="Header2" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#50FFFFFF"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <!--Column 3-->
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Property3}" Header="Header3" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Tell me if this helps you and solves your problem ;)

Comment: Finally, a method to do it that works! Thanks a bunch

Comment: Can you recommend where I should place `<setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="#"/>` I can make one column a different color, but not with alternating rows @Bruno

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question correctly. AlternatingRowBackground is a DataGrid property and cannot be set for a single column. To have the effect of alternating rows in the column you are modifying, you need to set a somewhat transparent background color or opacity < 1.